# Timestamp Field Incriminating

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table as such (with a timestamp and a varbinary)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CASE]
(
    [CASE_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CASE_TITLE] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CASE_STATUS] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [MODIFIED_TS] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [SYNCED_TS] [varbinary](8) NULL
)
```

Then I add an item to it, and update it...

```
UPDATE [CASE] 
SET CASE_STATUS = 'Something New' 
WHERE CASE_ID = 1
```

When I do that, then I update the `Synced_TS` column:

```
UPDATE [CASE] 
SET SYNCED_TS = MODIFIED_TS 
WHERE CASE_ID = 1
```

But then, when I run this....

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CAST(CONVERT(BIGINT, MODIFIED_TS) - CONVERT(INT, SYNCED_TS) AS DECIMAL)
FROM 
    [CASE]
WHERE 
    CAST(CONVERT(BIGINT, MODIFIED_TS) - CONVERT(INT, SYNCED_TS) AS DECIMAL) > 1
    OR SYNCED_TS IS NULL
```

I have two values that are totally different, for example, A0D, and A0A, its OK they are different, but shouldn't it be A0D, and A0C?

```
MODIFIED_TS         SYNCED_TS
---------------------------------------
0x0000000000000A0D  0x0000000000000A0A
```

The reason why its an issue, is that I am trying to convert it to an integer to compare it, so I can determine if the record needs to be synced or not.

Comment: Why are you comparing binary columns to timestamp columns?  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Because I want to compare the two timestamps, and make sure that it doesn't equal > 1 otherwise I am going to update the timestamp record after I sync that record to another table.

Comment: I'm curious why not just redefine modifed_ts as DateTime and use it?  Or add a LastModified DateTime?  Comparing DateTime to DateTime is much simpler than doing all of the conversions.  If DateTimeNow > LastModified Do your sync

Comment: Or make it a bool field, and when you update this table, mark it false.  Triggers your sync, marks it true when finished.  Many simpler ways than what you have outlined.  Simpler to implement, read, and maintain.